# Trying to run a SELECT sql query based on the dropdown list result. mySQL php

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu, recordset

I haven't designed a website for about 3 years now, so I am quite rusty to say the least. I have to fall back on Dreamweaver CS5 to help me out.
Right...

I want a page for news, and the user/customer will select from a dropdown menu the date (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR etc...) Now, I have a table in my mySQL database called 'news' where each row is referenced by these dates. I have already set up a Dynamic List for the date (a dropdown list.)

What I want is for the customer to select the date from the dropdown, and for the results to show in a Recordset underneath. I am assuming that the SQL query needs to be wrote something along the lines of:

SELECT date, subject, message
FROM news
WHERE date = $ XXXXXDROPDOWNLIST XXX $

As you can see, I made the last line up because I can't quite grasp how it should function. I am thinking that the dropdown list needs to be in a form which will POST and the table of results needs to be in a form which will GET.

Could somebody more technical than me please enlighten my dillema?

Thanks, Rob.

Code

```
mysql_select_db($database_rcc, $rcc);
$query_dropdowndate = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%M %Y') AS FORMATTEDDATE FROM news GROUP BY FORMATTEDDATE ORDER BY Date DESC  ";
$dropdowndate = mysql_query($query_dropdowndate, $rcc) or die(mysql_error());
$row_dropdowndate = mysql_fetch_assoc($dropdowndate);
$totalRows_dropdowndate = mysql_num_rows($dropdowndate);

mysql_select_db($database_rcc, $rcc);
$query_newsitems = "SELECT `Date`, Subject, Message FROM news WHERE date = $_POST['dropdowndate']";
$newsitems = mysql_query($query_newsitems, $rcc) or die(mysql_error());
$row_newsitems = mysql_fetch_assoc($newsitems);
$totalRows_newsitems = mysql_num_rows($newsitems);
?>



<form id="choosedate" name="choosedate" method="post" action="#">
  <label for="dropdowndate"></label>
  <select name="dropdowndate" id="dropdowndate">
    <?php
do {  
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_dropdowndate['FORMATTEDDATE']?>"<?php if (!(strcmp($row_dropdowndate['FORMATTEDDATE'], $row_dropdowndate['FORMATTEDDATE']))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>><?php echo $row_dropdowndate['FORMATTEDDATE']?></option>
    <?php
} while ($row_dropdowndate = mysql_fetch_assoc($dropdowndate));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($dropdowndate);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($dropdowndate, 0);
      $row_dropdowndate = mysql_fetch_assoc($dropdowndate);
  }
?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Subject</td>
      <td>Message</td>
    </tr>
    <?php do { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row_newsitems['Date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_newsitems['Subject']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row_newsitems['Message']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_newsitems = mysql_fetch_assoc($newsitems)); ?>
```

Some of this may look weird so let me explain... The dynamic list (dropdown) is called 'dropdowndate' and the form is called 'choosedate' There is a button called 'submit' to submit the form. FORMATTEDDATE is the name given to the recordset which gives the dropdown menu a dynamic list.

I want the value from that dynamic list when user's POST, to insert into the query as i mentioned ... SELECT `Date`, Subject, Message FROM news WHERE date = $_POST['dropdowndate']";  (THIS BIT IS PROBABLY WRONG)

Rob

Comment: Code please. It would be best to use $_POST['fieldname']

Comment: Don't forget to validate input or escape it, see mysqli_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT date, subject, message FROM news WHERE date = $_POST['fieldvalue']
```

The $_POST variable contains all the data sent when the form is posted. The field value should correspond to the name you give the select field.

This would be open to injection, so please ensure you use reasonable security measures.

If you wish to get the data without refreshing, you will need to use AJAX the following explains it beautifully http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/ if you need more info on that just ask.

Comment: @RobHatton I just read it, the part I am unsure of is, are you trying to do this without refreshing the page(AJAX) or does that not matter and you just want to refresh the form as normal. If you tell me that I can be more helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

An example of an HTML dropdown

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="animal">
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
</select>
</form>
```

An example how to catch the information with php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['animal'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I use this POST in a SQL SELECT query on the same page?

Comment: @RobHatton: `$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM pets WHERE type='.$POST['animal']);` You can adapt it to your purpose, don't forget to accept an answer, whatever it is.

Comment: @RobHatton, there is a sintax error above, the right sentence is `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pets WHERE type = '$_POST['animal']'");`, assuming that "animal" is a string field in your database. It's very important that you don't use `$_POST['animal']` directly in your query, you would be very vulneragle for [SQL Injection attacks](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=sql+injection+stack+overflow&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F601300%2Fwhat-is-sql-injection&ei=vu3kT53MA4T69QSL1b3lDg&usg=AFQjCNF_kQfZ7pJb7QOCb1VmHDMGFRPcNw&cad=rja).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the records to be loaded when the user select something from the drop down, or you want it to be loaded with the page?

In the first case you need to use Ajax, to bring the records in the background.

In the other case, you can do a statement like the one you posted when the page is loading.

Comment: Thanks for the input so far, I appreciate your help - even though I appear to be making a right dog's dinner of this php page!

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = $_POST['dropdowndate'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute = '$select'" or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: can i ask question here ? its really urgent to me :'(